# React Context API, large array, and application speed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js, loading, react-context

Application is built on Node/React/Express.

I have a table component and then a sub component for each row in the table that is generated dynamically from an array (`clients`) which is collected from the db by a react context api call and stored in state. I then map over the array and create a row (`Client` component) for each client.

```
 <TableBody>
   {clients.map(client => (
    <Client
     key={client.id}
     client={client}
     handleSnackBar={this.props.handleSnackBar}
     handleSendMail={this.props.handleSendMail}
    />
   ))}
 </TableBody>
```

On each of these rows is a button that can activate or deactivate the client's account.... now that the array (client list) is up to 1000 records, it's taking a solid 3 seconds to activate or deactivate the account and reflect the changes.

I'm looking for a) any issues with doing it how I'm doing it, b) suggestions for speeding up this process and optimizing the code, c) is Redux a better option for this? Or, I guess, d) do I have unrealistic expectations and I should just add a loading spinner and call it good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Where is your code to activate and desactivate a client? In the Table component or in the Client component?
2. How did you update a client item? You update the whole array of clients or just the current item?
3. Did you use PureComponent for your Client component?

For 1.
It is better to put activate/desactivate stuff in your Client component. So each Client component manage his state and that way when you activate/desactivate a client, it is not your whole table that is updated.

For 2.
Like as said in 1. Better manage all stuff for each Client component. You can create a UncontrolledComponent, so the component is not update each time the state of the Table component changed. For that see the doc here https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

For 3.
When you use a huge list of data, it is better to use a PureComponent because it manage better his state and boost the performance. See the doc for more informations https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

Comment: #1. The activate and deactivate functions are located in the Client component. Each row manages its own state.
#2. Express route, targeting the client by ID. Then dispatch sends an updated entire array to context... I think maybe here you are right that I could try and just target the one client inside that array.
#3 I'll look into the PureComponent thing... thank you! This was helpful!

Comment: Okay! And the two others?

Comment: Don't forget to mark as resolved if it does the job!

Comment: Switching over to a PureComponent reduces rendering time from 4s to 2.5... so that's a huge difference in itself!

Comment: Cool!! And the #2 ? I think it'll help the most

Comment: I haven't been able to look into this one yet... but hopefully this afternoon :) I'll let you know!